# inverse of a funtion

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

I'm trying to calculate the inverse of the function:
$$y= \tan \left( \cos^{-1}  \frac{x}{x+2} \right)  $$

In my opinion it is $y=  \frac{2 \cos ( \tan^{-1} x )}{1-\cos ( \tan^{-1} x )}  $ but in my book it is reported :
$f(x)\begin{cases} -2\left( \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x^2} \right) &  x < 0\\
-1 & x = 0\\2 \left( \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}{x^2} \right) & x>0 \end{cases}$

Can someone explain me the passages?

Comment: No.. do you know what an inverse function is?

Comment: I'm interested only in the form

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$y= \tan\big[ \arccos(f(x)) \big]=\frac{\sqrt{1-f(x)^2}}{f(x)}$$  could help you.

Comment: Applying your formula I can't have the result , but where did you find it? I don't remember to have seen it

Comment: @Anne. There are so many identities involving trigonometric functions ! I am glad to have remembered this one (at my age !!). Cheers :-)

Comment: @Anne,  here are those identities as the author meant, https://brilliant.org/wiki/inverse-trigonometric-identities/

Answer (score 1):

Let's first see your solution,
$$f(x)=\tan \left( \cos^{-1} \frac{x}{x+2} \right) \\ f^{-1}(x)= \frac{2 \cos ( \tan^{-1} x )}{1-\cos ( \tan^{-1} x )} $$

Fo example, Consider $x=-1$, $f(0)= \tan \pi  = 0 $ , and by your result we do **not** get the same value. It can't be the inverse function anyway.

Assuming that you don't know much about inverse function,

You can read it [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/functions-inverses/#:%7E:text=Forgot%20password%3F-,Inverse%20Functions,read%20as%20a%20negative%20exponent.), I'll just use the facts.

For a relation to be a function, every element in domain must have only one image in the co-domain. Thus only bijective functions are invertible.

Usually, it is needed to first prove that the function is bijective or not. I'll skip that in this answer.

[image]

As you can see it's bijective, and the domain is restricted to $x \ge -1$ because $-1\le \frac{x}{x+2} \le 1$

$\cos^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{x+2} \right)$ can be written as $\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{2\sqrt{x+1}}{x} \right)$

So, $$ y=\tan \left( \cos^{-1} \frac{x}{x+2} \right)  \\ = \frac{2\sqrt{x+1}}{x} $$

Rearrange, and square both sides to remove the sqaure root, find the roots in terms of $x$.

The radical term can have both ($+$ and $-$) signs,
$$\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}$$

and to see which sign to use, it's best to see assume couple of values of $x$ and get the value(s) of $y$ from the original function, and see which sign satisfies that relation, in the inverse function.

Like $f(-1)=0$ so $f^{-1}(0)=-1$ must hold true.

Be careful when dealing with squares or square roots, because they can have restrictions, hence the function is piecewise. It is easier to that by looking at the graph, though in an exam you won't have it. It's useful to check  the domain, and where your function is negative, positive, zero

---

**EDIT:**   for converting one Inverse trigonometric function to another Inverse trigonometric function, quickly, see the triangle, in yoir case, let $$ \theta =cos^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{1} \right) \\ \cos \theta =y$$ here, adjacent side, $BC=y$ and hypotenuse is $1$ , find out the other side by Pythagoras theorem, $AB=\sqrt{1-y^2}$

now you have
All three sides, you can find any trigonometric ratio, by their basic definition. for example,  $\sin \theta = \frac{AB}{AC} =\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1}$  $$ \theta = \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{1-y^2})$$ or $$cos^{-1}(y)=\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{1-y^2})$$
[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote " 
$\cos^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{x+2} \right)$ can be written as $\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{2\sqrt{x+1}}{x} \right)$  "

Comment: @Anne, we basically define trigonometric functions as ratio of sides. cosine is defined as side adjacent to the angle upon the hypotenuse. And tangent is defined as side opposite to the angle over the side adjacent to it. Let me it edit, so it's clearer to understand.

Comment: now I see, but I can't still understand why it is done the distinction between the case $x>0$, $x<0$ and $x=0$

Comment: Did you get the function? Type it here.

Comment: Yes, and the result is the same on the book

Comment: @Anne, the problem arises during conversation. because $\cos^{-1}(x) \in [0, \pi]$ and $\tan^{-1}(x) \in \left[ -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ the range is conflicting. $\cos^{-1}(x)$ lies in $\left[ 0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ for $1\ge x> 0$, on converting into arctan, there's no problem in this interval of $x$ as, $\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} \right)$ all positive values in its domain. Because $\left( \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} \right)$ has all values in $[0,\infty)$. See all the graphs individually for better understanding.

Comment: But when $-1\le x<0, \ \cos^{-1}(x) \in \left[ \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi \right]$, this is not in the range of $\arctan$ so we must modify it to get Desired ranges, i.e. $(-\infty,0)$ , in this particular case if you add a minus sign, it'll work out as $ -\left( \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} \right)$ gives all values in $(-\infty,0)$, which will satisfy the required condition for $\arctan$ , i.e. all negative values. See all the conversation identities, and try to prove them algebraically after you've gotten some understanding from graphs.